# Access array from other function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Hello i'm trying to access an array from a function what i'am returning work, it's an array but the result in my function "onChangeClient" always display the same "undefined". why ?

Typescript:

[image: 1]

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Type the code.

Comment: Declare `returnArr` outside of `ref.once` callback then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript (and hence TypeScript) uses *lexical scope*, meaning you cannot create an `Array` in an inner function and access it from outside. What you can do: Create the array in the *outer* function (`getRessource`) and return it from there.

```
async getRessource(id) {
  var ref = ... elided ...
  const returnArray = []; // define it here
  await ref.once('value' ... elided ... );
  return returnArray;
}
```